# `command` vs `type` - Locate program file in user's PATH

Tags: shell, path

I need locate program file in user's PATH. I found few solution, the best are `command` and `type`.

Which is better, faster, UNIX-like way and why?

```
command -v <application>
type -p <application>
```

Comment: You can refer this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: I cannot find this, it's explain everything: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/31887. Thanks @Gnouc!

Comment: just use `command -p ${this is run with a path guaranteed to find all standard utilities}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variant `command -v` is the defined in the POSIX standard,
so it is exactly the "UNIX-like way to do it".

For the standard, see 
[POSIX - Shell & Utilities - command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22_04)

For all the details, and still much more details: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)